# Implementing recursive function with __iter__ method in a Python class

Tags: python, recursion, iteration, generator

So I'm working on a problem in which I'm to create a Python Class to generate all Permutations of a list and I'm running across the following questions:

1. I can complete this easily with a simple recursive function, but as a class it seems like I would want to use the **iter** method.  My method calls a recursive function (list_all) that's almost identical to my **iter**, which is very unsettling.  How do I modify my recursive function to be in compliance with best practices for **iter**?
2. I wrote this code, saw that it worked, and I feel like I don't understand it!  I try to trace the code line by line in a test case, but to me it looks like the first element in the list is frozen each time, and the rest of the list is shuffled.  Instead the output comes out in an unexpected order.  I'm not understanding something!

Thanks!

```
class permutations():
  def __init__(self, ls):
    self.list = ls

  def __iter__(self):
    ls = self.list
    length = len(ls)
    if length <= 1:
      yield ls
    else:
      for p in self.list_all(ls[1:]):
        for x in range(length):
          yield p[:x] + ls[0:1] + p[x:]  

  def list_all(self, ls):
    length = len(ls)
    if length <= 1:
      yield ls
    else:
      for p in self.list_all(ls[1:]):
        for x in range(length):
          yield p[:x] + ls[0:1] + p[x:]
```

Comment: If your function works well, why would you want to squeeze it into a class? If the point is to lazily generate the permutations, just use `yield` in your function.

Comment: I am in agreement with this.  The word class was specifically stated in the question, so I'm trying to think how I would make it an iterable class that interfaces with the __iter__ method.

Answer (score 2):

Just call `self.list_all` from `__iter__`:

```
class permutations():
  def __init__(self, ls):
    self.list = ls

  def __iter__(self):
    for item in self.list_all(self.list):
      yield item

  def list_all(self, ls):
    length = len(ls)
    if length <= 1:
      yield ls
    else:
      for p in self.list_all(ls[1:]):
        for x in range(length):
          yield p[:x] + ls[0:1] + p[x:]
```

Comment: This is one of those bittersweet moments in the learning process.  Happy I can get the desired result.  Irritated I didn't make this connection earlier.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `list_all` method is already a generator, so you can return that directly in `__iter__`:

```
class permutations():
    def __init__(self, ls):
        self.list = ls

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.list_all(self.list)

    def list_all(self, ls):
        length = len(ls)
        if length <= 1:
            yield ls
        else:
            for p in self.list_all(ls[1:]):
                for x in range(length):
                    yield p[:x] + ls[0:1] + p[x:]
```

This is both cleaner to read and executes faster.

You also have option is to define `list_all` inside `__iter__`.

```
class permutations2():
    def __init__(self, ls):
        self.list = ls

    def __iter__(self):
        def list_all(ls):
            length = len(ls)
            if length <= 1:
                yield ls
            else:
                for p in list_all(ls[1:]):
                    for x in range(length):
                        yield p[:x] + ls[0:1] + p[x:]
                    
        return list_all(self.list)
```

Timing `permutations` vs my `permutations2` gives almost identical results.